# dumpsys battery only works when executed from PC

Tags: android, adb, dump, dumpsys

I've built a small app with the purpose of running dumpsys commands on device as a development helper. I've granted it the permission `DUMP` and `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` via adb and the app is installed as system app.

It runs commands just fine, but often it puts out a service not found error.

If I execute `adb shell dumpsys battery` on my PC I get infos about the battery.
If I execute `dumpsys battery` on my device via my app I get the error

```
dumpsys battery  error Can't find service: battery
```

Running the command with `adb shell` in front obvioulsy wont work, because these interfaces are only needed to get the command from pc to the device in my understanding.

How can I run dumpsys commands on device without getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app won't have permission to connect to the *batterystats* service unlike `adb`.

Comment: Is there a possibility to give it that permission or is this impossible to do in an app?

Comment: You need a **system app**, an app which came as pre-installed or as a system.img (AOSP system) app and signed with the system certificate. System apps can access platform (app-framework) level API call.

Comment: Oh so I'd have to tinker with the system.img? Sounds very stressful. Thanks for your help!